# Get list of stored procedures from a U-SQL database

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is that a way to get list of all stored procedures (and functions) for a U-SQL database? It would be great if I could get full stored procedure name and it's body script.

I'm building a simple tool for automating of creating/updating U-SQL stored procedures. I'm trying to find a way to implement the operations:
deleted all stored procedures, check stored procedure existence, compare exited stored procedure's body with the new one.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the different client SDKs have commands to enumerate your meta data objects. Eg. `Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogItem` in Powershell. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-powershell. Similar commands exists in the other SDKs.